# For loop won't pass i variable to Jquery function inside the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I've a for-loop and it won't pass it's **i** variable or any kind of a variable into Jquery function coded to run with every loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    $('#frame-' + i + '').fadeOut(function () {
        ALERT(i);
        document.getElementById('frame-' + i + '').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'img/' + result.cat[i].id + '.png';

    });
    $('#frame-' + i + '').fadeIn();

}
```

I found that I can use .on or .bind functions but I've no idea how it should be done with fadeOut().

fadeOut.on() won't work.

Any suggestions to get this working?

Comment: **replace** `frame-'+i+''` with `frame-'+i`

Comment: @DipeshParmar that's not the issue though as `i` is out of scope in the callback.

Comment: Looks like a closure issue

Comment: `alert()` is _not_ the same as `ALERT()`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i know but extra `'` will give error

Comment: @DipeshParmar - it works fine only issue is it wont pass any variable into the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is by the time your fadeOut completes, the for loop has already completed and as such, the value of `i` that the fade code is reading, will always be the same (the last value).

Create a closure to pass the value of `i`. This gives you a local copy of `i` which won't be overwritten by the for loop. Also change `ALERT()` to `alert()` (Javascript is case sensitive).

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        $('#frame-' + i).fadeOut(function () {
            alert(i);
            document.getElementById('frame-' + i + '').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'img/' + result.cat[i].id + '.png';

        }).fadeIn();
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Closure again!!!

```
$.each(result, function (i, res) {
    $('#frame-' + i + '').fadeOut(function () {
        alert(i);
        $(this).find('img').get(0).attr('src', 'img/' + res.cat.id + '.png');
    }).fadeIn();
})
```